# vb 2010 Generate random numbers without repeating

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am able to generate a random number, but what I am unable to do is prevent the random numbers from repeating. I would like it so that there are no duplicates of numbers. This is my code so far,

```
    Dim rndnumber As Integer

    Randomize()

    rndnumber = Int(Rnd() * 52) + 1

    ListBox1.Items.Add(rndnumber)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks a lot like deck of cards to me, which implies what you really want to do is **shuffle** the deck. Of course, the best algorithm for shuffling a set is the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
Private rand As New Random()
Public Function Shuffle(Of T)(ByVal items As IList(Of T)) As IList(Of T)
    For i As Integer = items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Dim j As Integer = rand.Next(i + 1)
        Dim temp As T= items(i)
        items(i) = items(j)
        items(j) = temp
    Next
    Return items
End Function

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Shuffle(Enumerable.Range(0,52).ToList()).ToArray())
```

Comment: the addrange part for the listbox ends up giving me an error i do not know how to fix. the error states "overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Addrange' can be called with these arguments"

Answer (score 0):

' My fun program for teaching my friends about VB 2010

Public Class Form1

```
Private miNdx As Integer, miSaveVerb As Integer
Private miSaveWhat As Integer, miSaveWith As Integer, miSaveWhere As Integer
Private msVerbs(6) As String
Private msWhat(6) As String
Private msWhere(6) As String
Private msWhile(6) As String

Private Sub cmdGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGo.Click
    Dim iRnd As Integer
    Dim sVerb As String, sWhat As String, sWhere As String, sWhile As String

    iRnd = RNDGenerator(miSaveVerb)
    sVerb = msVerbs(iRnd)

    iRnd = RNDGenerator(miSaveWhat)
    sWhat = msWhat(iRnd)

    iRnd = RNDGenerator(miSaveWhere)
    sWhere = msWhere(iRnd)

    iRnd = RNDGenerator(miSaveWith)
    sWhile = msWhile(iRnd)

    Me.txtDisplay.Text = Me.txtName.Text & sVerb & sWhat & sWhile & sWhere

End Sub

Private Function RNDGenerator(ByRef iSave As Integer) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Randomize()
    Do
        i = Int(miNdx * Rnd() + 1)
        Debug.Print(i)
    Loop While iSave = i
    iSave = i
    RNDGenerator = i

End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.txtDisplay.Text = vbNullString
    Me.txtName.Text = vbNullString
    miNdx = 6
    msVerbs(1) = " eats"
    msVerbs(2) = " smashes"
    msVerbs(3) = " pukes"
    msVerbs(4) = " sucks"
    msVerbs(5) = " farts"
    msVerbs(6) = " licks"

    msWhat(1) = " shit"
    msWhat(2) = " scum"
    msWhat(3) = " dirt"
    msWhat(4) = " filth"
    msWhat(5) = " scabs"
    msWhat(6) = " boogers"

    msWhere(1) = " in my house"
    msWhere(2) = " in the bathroom"
    msWhere(3) = " in the kitchen"
    msWhere(4) = " in a Sandbox"
    msWhere(5) = " at the whore house"
    msWhere(6) = " in a muddy hole"

    msWhile(1) = " while smiling"
    msWhile(2) = " while making puke puddles"
    msWhile(3) = " while playing with poop"
    msWhile(4) = " while smelling farts"
    msWhile(5) = " while stinking bad"
    msWhile(6) = " while laughing"

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Why are you using `Randomize` and `Rnd`?...those are for legacy code involving VB6 and below.  Use [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1) and [Random.Next()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1).  Use the [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement) keyword instead of setting the function name. Also, this question is almost five years old, look at the dates before you add to a question.  Another thing...welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score -3):

Code generates a random selection from an ArrayList (so could be integers, strings, image files etc) - here just 52 integers to represent a pack of cards.
Code ensures that duplicates cannot be chosen by removing items from the input ArrayList. The random selections are added to the output ArrayList (or as requested in the question to a ListBox )

```
Dim RandNo as new Random
Dim Deck as ArrayList
Dim Shuffle as ArrayList 'or just use ListBox as in Question

For Counter = 0 to 51
    'Just integers to represent the 52 cards, but could be Strings 5D, 6H etc
    'or even card images
    Deck.Add(Counter)
Next

Dim Temp as Integer
For Counter = 0 to 51
    Temp = Deck.Item(RandNo.Next,0,Deck.Count - 1))
    Shuffle.Add(Temp)  'or for question - ListBox1.Items.Add(Temp)
    Deck.Remove(Temp)
Next
```

Comment: You have posted a dump of code without explaining what the code does or how it compares to Joel's solution. Please consider [edit]ing your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Your explanation goes a long way to improving your answer, but perhaps you could use more up-to-date code, such as not using an ArrayList, and maybe use Enumerable.Range to generate the numbers in the first place.